# AN 8.30 Great thoughts, thoughts of great man, thing-able, (de-)touch-able for everyone? (thinking in first jhāna)

Tags: nirvana, jhana, abhidhamma

Coming from [here, analysis of AN 8.30](https://notesonthedhamma.blogspot.com/2021/10/an-830-maybe-try-having-faith-in-buddha.html).

> Good, Anuruddha, very good.
> It’s good that you think
> these thoughts of a great person:

Does good householder think that certain (all) people are capable to think such thoughts?
So how then could certain delight in such thoughts? What then would one, seeing this, start to think for himself instead to try to make a dead dog walk? In what would he delight and sacrifices into himself? What does good householder here desire to think?

Are thought of a great man only think-able for great or by everyone? What happens if a ordinary starts to give them public thoughts?

And in the case thinking not possible for everybody here and now, what would be the prerequisite to get the point?

What's the matter with proper attention and good association here? Could that be a way out?

Comment: some of your questions unclear, such as  >>What then would one, seeing this, start to think for himself instead to try to make a dead dog walk? In what would he delight and sacrifices into himself? What does good householder here desire to think?

Answer (score 0):

If we read the later part of [AN 8.30](https://suttacentral.net/an8.30/en/bodhi), we will find that this is targeted at monks (bhikkhus) and not lay followers.

For example:

> “When it was said: ‘This Dhamma is for one who is content, not for one
> who is discontent,’ with reference to what was this said? Here, a
> **bhikkhu** is content with any kind of robes, almsfood, lodgings, and
> medicines and provisions for the sick. When it was said: ‘This Dhamma
> is for one who is content, not for one who is discontent,’ it is with
> reference to this that this was said.
>
> “When it was said: ‘This Dhamma is for one who resorts to solitude,
> not for one who delights in company,’ with reference to what was this
> said? Here, when a **bhikkhu** resorts to solitude, bhikkhus, bhikkhunīs,
> male lay followers, female lay followers, kings, royal ministers,
> heads of other sects, and disciples belonging to other sects approach
> him. In each case, with a mind that slants, slopes, and inclines to
> seclusion, withdrawn, delighting in renunciation, he gives them a talk
> invariably concerned with dismissing them. When it was said: ‘This
> Dhamma is for one who resorts to solitude, not for one who delights in
> company,’ it is with reference to this that this was said.
> [AN 8.30](https://suttacentral.net/an8.30/en/bodhi)

There is further indication below that this is targeted at monks (bhikkhus) and not lay followers.

> “When you reflect upon these eight thoughts of a great person and gain
> at will … these four jhānas … then, while you dwell contentedly, **your
> scraps of almsfood** will seem to you as a dish of rice cleaned of black
> grains and served with many gravies and curries seems to a householder
> or a householder’s son; and they will serve for your delight, relief,
> and ease, and for entering upon nibbāna.
>
> “When you reflect upon these eight thoughts of a great person and gain
> at will … these four jhānas … then, while you dwell contentedly, **your
> dwelling place at the foot of a tree** will seem to you as a house with
> a peaked roof, plastered inside and out, draft-free, with bolts
> fastened and shutters closed, seems to a householder or a
> householder’s son; and it will serve for your delight, relief, and
> ease, and for entering upon nibbāna.
>
> “When you reflect upon those eight thoughts of a great person and gain
> at will … these four jhānas … then, while you dwell contentedly, **your
> bed and seat made of straw** will seem to you as a couch spread with
> rugs, blankets, and covers, with an excellent covering of antelope
> hide, with a canopy above and red bolsters at both ends, seems to a
> householder or a householder’s son; and it will serve for your
> delight, relief, and ease, and for entering upon nibbāna.
>
> “When you reflect upon these eight thoughts of a great person and gain
> at will … these four jhānas … then, while you dwell contentedly, **your
> medicine of fermented cow’s urine** will seem to you as various
> medicaments of ghee, butter, oil, honey, and molasses seem to a
> householder or a householder’s son; and it will serve for your
> delight, relief, and ease, and for entering upon nibbāna.
> [AN 8.30](https://suttacentral.net/an8.30/en/bodhi)

So, does this mean that the Dhamma is only for monks and not for lay followers? Does this mean anybody who is interested in Buddhism MUST eventually become monks?

No. Definitely not.

There is the duality of the path according to [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html).

There is Right View with effluents for lay persons and the Noble Right View for monks. Similarly, for Right Speech, Right Livelihood etc. there's the version with effluents and the version which is noble.

What is Right Livelihood for lay persons for e.g. carrying out the business of a merchant selling clothes, or the profession of a doctor, for example, is not Right Livelihood for monks. The former is with effluents. The latter is the noble version.

> "And what is right view? Right view, I tell you, is of two sorts:
> There is right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
> acquisitions [of becoming]; there is right view that is noble, without
> effluents, transcendent, a factor of the path.
>
> "And what is the right view with effluents, siding with merit,
> resulting in acquisitions? 'There is what is given, what is offered,
> what is sacrificed. There are fruits & results of good & bad actions.
> There is this world & the next world. There is mother & father. There
> are spontaneously reborn beings; there are contemplatives & brahmans
> who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the
> next after having directly known & realized it for themselves.' This
> is the right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
> acquisitions.
>
> "And what is the right view that is noble, without effluents,
> transcendent, a factor of the path? The discernment, the faculty of
> discernment, the strength of discernment, analysis of qualities as a
> factor for awakening, the path factor of right view[1](https://suttacentral.net/an8.30/en/bodhi) in one
> developing the noble path whose mind is noble, whose mind is without
> effluents, who is fully possessed of the noble path. This is the right
> view that is noble, without effluents, transcendent, a factor of the
> path.
> [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)

So, does this mean that the study of the Dhamma and the practise of meditation is only for monks?

No. That's not true. The Buddha told Anathapindika and 500 other lay followers to practise the meditation leading to jhana, when they can find free time. He did not tell them to become monks.

He said their charity towards monks is commendable but they shouldn't think that this is the only thing they should do as householders. They should also practise meditation and reflect on the teachings.

> Then Anathapindika the **householder**, surrounded by about **500 lay
> followers**, went to the Blessed One and, on arrival, having bowed
> down to him, sat to one side. As he was sitting there the Blessed One
> said to him, "**Householder**, you have provided the community of
> monks with robes, alms food, lodgings, & medicinal requisites for the
> sick, but you shouldn't rest content with the thought, 'We have
> provided the community of monks with robes, alms food, lodgings, &
> medicinal requisites for the sick.' **So you should train yourself,
> 'Let's periodically enter & remain in seclusion & rapture.'** That's
> how you should train yourself."
> [Piti Sutta (AN 5.176)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.176.than.html)

Renowned sutta scholar Piya Tan wrote in [his commentary on Piti Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/19.8-Piti-S-a5.176-piya.pdf) that:

> Until recently (even up to the late 20th century), there is a common
> wrong view that spiritual training, especially mental cultivation or
> meditation, is only the domain of the monastic. The laity merely makes
> merit by serving and supporting the monastics. However, **it is clear
> from the Pīti Sutta here that spiritual development by way of mental
> cultivation is just as important for the laity.**

Sometimes, monks like Devadatta ([Iti 89](https://suttacentral.net/iti89/en/sujato)) or Sati ([MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/sujato)) are wrong teachers and a lay householder like Citta ([SN 41.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn41.5/en/sujato)) is the right teacher.

One of the monks that Citta taught, by the name of Ven. Kamabhu, said:

> “You’re fortunate, householder, so very fortunate, to traverse the
> Buddha’s deep teachings with the eye of wisdom.”
> [SN 41.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn41.5/en/sujato)

Many lay followers attained stream entry in the stories of the suttas.

So, while the path of the monk is superior to the path of the lay follower, and is in fact, the noble path, but the path of the lay follower is definitely existing and is legitimate.

And the lay follower is not just meant to provide alms to monks, but is also meant to study the Dhamma and practise it to the extent that is possible to him. Of course, he can also choose to become a monk later if he wants to, but this is not mandatory.

It's as though the monk is like the full time professional practitioner, like a full time professional football player. And the lay person is the casual practitioner, like someone who plays football casually in his free time.

We cannot tell the casual football player that he cannot play football at all, just because he is not a full time professional football player.

What is important is that we shouldn't waste our precious time, and do the best that we can, as the Dhammapada says:

> Those who in youth have not led the holy life, or have failed to
> acquire wealth, languish like old cranes in the pond without fish.
>
> Those who in youth have not lead the holy life, or have failed to
> acquire wealth, lie sighing over the past, like worn out arrows (shot
> from) a bow.
> [Dhammapada 155 - 156](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.11.budd.html)

Comment: So laypeople aren't able to atain Jhanas or what should the excluding of lay people being "great people" here suggest, aside that thinking that answer might have lacked of proper attention possible, good householder? It doesn't seem that good householder got the point of question at all and prefers papancing on it, right? Auf Deutsch: 'Don mag da gerade mal wieder eine Windmühle attackieren".

Comment: Maybe, even if certain in traumata, he likes to reread the Question and answer instead on it as there isn't any matter of kind of way of livelihood inside at all. (Elsewhere, maybe apply the 'this was taught to homeless' to correct 100 of answers)

Answer (score 0):

Good householder Frank, maybe:

First, a not yet completely great person would think:

(1) ‘This Dhamma is for one of few-desires,
not for one of many-desires.
(2) This Dhamma is for one who is content,
not for one who is dis-content.
(3) This Dhamma is for one who is reclusive,
not for one who who delights-in-social-gathering.
(4) This Dhamma is for one of aroused-vigor,
not for one who is lazy.
(5) This Dhamma is for one who has established-mindfulness,
not for one of muddled-mindfulness.
(6) This Dhamma is for one who is concentrated,
not for one who is un-concentrated.
(7) This Dhamma is for one endowed with discernment,
not for one of dubious-discernment.’

and as possible being made aware or get aware himself, that having fallen into the Papanca-trap (composed out of the three papanca-dhammas: view, graving, conceit) in all cases for himself, cutting him off from Noble attainments, remembers the 8. and takes the first without slippering away by papanca by heart, gotten back on right attention, track, ye way of practice of a Noble One:

(8) ‘This Dhamma is for one who enjoys non-proliferation-[of-objectification],-1- who delights in non-proliferation,
not-for-one who enjoys & delights in proliferation-[of-objectification].’

(it's importand not to let go of thoughts till the highest release, thoughtless acts will otherwise remain)

de-powered by:

[image]

Comment: sorry, I still don't know what you're asking of me. My article you linked in the OP was specific on the topic that the 8 great thoughts (vitakka), has to be the same vitakka of first jhana, contrary to LBT (late buddhist texts) position that vitakka in first jhana means "not thinking, just placing the mind".  It sounds like you're asking me something outside the scope of my article on that narrow topic. II'd be happy to comment if I knew what you were after.

Comment: So far as I know, most other users of this site don't see advertisements like the one in your screen-shot -- and you do see them, because you use throw-away unregistered user accounts. I'm not sure about this but the Stack Exchange network implements a "[Reduced ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)" privilege -- that privilege is undocumented on this site, but I don't see ads so I guess it exists. I mean, users like frankk (whose reputation is over 1000) won't see the ads you see. You wouldn't see them either, except that you insist on using unprivileged user accounts.

Comment: Good householer Frank is always welcome for thoughts and issues with no requirements to speak on traders sites. And sure most useful to let go of trying getting death dogs walk and waste ones time nurishing on it.. Good householder Chris, since years does he ignore for what he works and sacrifices... yet it was just an ironic on the topic, but with lack of proper attention sure hard to trace. Nothing to worry as for oneself.

Answer (score -4):

The question asked is:

> ***And in the case thinking not possible for everybody here and now, what  would be the prerequisite to get the point? What's the matter with
> proper attention and good association here? Could that be a way out?***

Per [AN 10.61](https://suttacentral.net/an10.61/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=true), the prerequisite to get the point is proper attention and good association. For example, due to lacking good association, the thoughts of FrankK are:

[image]

An example, of good association are the thoughts of Ajahn Buddhadasa ([given five Honorary Doctorates by Thai universities](https://www.buddhanet.net/biobudas.htm)), which were/are:

[image]

When the inferior & mundane with wrong view are lost in imaginings/misconstruings (maññati) about a profound & lofty Dhamma subject (such as 'jhana'), if they wish to be wise, they will rely on the superior, such as the Ariya Sangha.

For example, [AN 8.30](https://suttacentral.net/an8.30/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=true) says:

> Therefore, Anuruddha, also reflect on (vitakkehi; 2nd person singular imperative) this eighth thought of a great person: (8) ‘This Dhamma is for one who **delights in non-proliferation**, who takes **delight in nonproliferation**, not for one who delights in proliferation, who takes delight in proliferation.’
>
> “When, Anuruddha, you reflect on (vitakkessasi; 2nd person singular [future active](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Textual-Studies/Grammar/Guide-to-Pali-Grammar.htm)) these eight thoughts of a great
> person, then, as much as you wish (ākaṅkhissasi; 2nd person singular [future active](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Textual-Studies/Grammar/Guide-to-Pali-Grammar.htm)), secluded from sensual pleasures,
> secluded from unwholesome states, you will enter (upasampajja; gerund, active, absolutive) and dwell (viharissasi; 2nd person singular [future active](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Textual-Studies/Grammar/Guide-to-Pali-Grammar.htm)) in the
> first jhāna, which consists of rapture and pleasure born of seclusion,
> accompanied by thought and examination.
>
> “**When you reflect on these eight thoughts of a great person**, then, as
> much as you wish, **with the subsiding of thought and examination**, you
> will enter and dwell in the second jhāna, which has internal placidity
> and unification of mind and consists of rapture and pleasure born of
> concentration, without thought and examination.
>
> “**When you reflect on these eight thoughts of a great person**, then, as
> much as you wish, with the fading away as well of rapture, **you will
> dwell equanimous and, mindful and clearly comprehending**, experience
> pleasure with the body; you will enter and dwell in the third jhāna of
> which the noble ones declare: ‘He is equanimous, mindful, one who
> dwells happily.’
>
> “**When you reflect on these eight thoughts of a great person**, then, as
> much as you wish, with the abandoning of pleasure and pain, and with
> the previous passing away of joy and sadness, **you will enter and dwell
> in the fourth jhāna**, neither painful nor pleasant, which has
> purification of mindfulness by equanimity.

Here, AN 8.30, using active future verbs, says every jhana can be attained by reflecting on the eight thoughts of a great person. For example, about the 1st jhana, AN 8.30 says when there is thought about the eight thoughts, the 1st jhana will be attained, which includes the vitakka of jhana. This shows the reflecting of the eight thoughts is not the vitakka & vicara of the 1st jhana (because one type of vitakka is used to enter/attain & abide in another type of vitakka). Therefore, obviously, per the good association with Ajahn Buddhadasa, the reflecting/use of ordinary 'verbal thought' occurs prior to jhana, which contains another type of 'non-verbal vitakka', namely, 'directing the mind'.

To reiterate & emphasise the last of eight thoughts, which is about practising **non-proliferation**, MN 19 says:

> If I think and ponder upon this thought even for a night, even for a
> day, even for a night and day, I see nothing to fear from it. But with
> excessive thinking and pondering I might tire my body, and when the
> body is tired, the mind becomes strained, and when the mind is
> strained, it is **far from concentration**.’ **So I steadied my mind
> internally, quieted it, brought it to singleness, and concentrated it.
> Why is that? So that my mind should not be strained**.... Tireless
> energy was aroused in me and unremitting mindfulness was established,
> my body was tranquil and untroubled, my mind concentrated and unified.
> Quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unwholesome
> states, I entered upon and abided in the first jhāna...

Therefore, when a puthujjana places faith in Ariya Sangha, such as Ajahn Buddhadasa or Ajahn Brahm, it appears impossible the puthujjana & non-jhana attainer would regard the reflecting referred to in AN 8.30 as occurring in the 1st jhana. Ajahn Budhadadasa & Ajahn Brahm have advised us ordinary vitakka is not the same as the vitakka of jhana. Naturally, if we had merely a small amount of common sense, we would logically concludes ordinary vitakka cannot occur together with ekaggata citta. Regardless, when the Ajahns of high repute tell jhana vitakka is not the same as ordinary vitakka, we should consider what they say.

Of course, if Ajahn Brahm preaches reincarnation to us, we do not have to believe this, because the Suttas already tell us reincarnation is not related to the Noble Path. But when Ajahn Brahm tells us vitakka is a subtle movement of the mind towards the rapture of jhana, it is wise to have faith in him, rather than continue the kamma of making endless arguments & baseless insults on the internet.

The above example shows the benefit (namely, non-delusion) of association with good persons.